# Sublime Text 3 macOS Save As always appends file extension

Tags: save, sublimetext3, macos-sierra, finder

When I create a new document in SublimeText 3 on OSX/macOS (Sierra), and the file type is set from either a previous document or detected, when I try to save the new file and explicitly save the document (remove the extension, change it to something else), it does not obey and always uses the file type association extension.

Is this a bug or am I missing some config on either ST or OSX? I would assume/expect the Save File dialog text shouldn't be disobeyed like this.

[image]

Save dialog shows the extension, but I don't really want to save it as LESS, that's just a "mistake."

[image]

So I remove the `.less` from the file name in the dialog:

[image]

Hit save, and the `.less` comes back in the saved filename! This is just annoying.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the LESS syntax set on the file you're working on? That's typically how the Save As... dialog gets its suffixes.

Comment: Seems like it might be a feature; it suggests the extension of the current syntax and indeed will put it back if you remove it (including if you just insert a period to get a blank extension, netting you a file with a double period in it). However if I change the extension manually to something else, it warns me and asks if I want to use it, and it accepts the other extensions assigned to the same syntax (e.g. `sql` allows `ddl` and `dml`). There doesn't seem to be a setting to control it.

Comment: @OdatNurd If there was that warning--which I'm familiar with in macOS itself--that would be fine. It's more that I already have show all file extensions turned on, and save a file in the dialog with filename `filename`, it's still saved as `x.ext`. Really comes off as a bug imho.

Comment: @MattDMo yep I do - on purpose, and it behaves as expected up to the point where I delete the extension and it comes back without warning. In the past I've been burned by it by not realizing I'd had an `.sh` appended for a bash script I wanted to be extensionless.

Comment: @Brian in my test (MacOS 10.10.5 and ST3 Build 3126) when I tried to save an SQL file as text, I got a pop up telling me that I was using a non-standard extension for this file and it asked me if I wanted to continue; I said yes and it saved it as `.txt` like I said. Does that not happen for you?

Comment: @Brian unless you meant that it doesn't say anything if you remove the extension entirely and just put it back (which you likely did) in which case never mind me, my brain seems to have switched into neutral or something.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior on Windows 10 using Build 3125. I opened a new file with Python syntax, typed something, then hit Save As. When I type in a name with no extension, `.py` was automatically added. However, in a new file, if I Save As `filename.txt`, it is saved as a text file.

Comment: @MattDMo It may not be on the `Save As...` function explicitly - maybe I need to update my description. It's when you create a new untitled file and have the filetype set to Bash (`.sh`), for example. In a new untitled file set to bash, using Cmd-S, the Save As dialog comes up on OSX, within which I have no control over the extension used if I want to use anything other than `.sh`.